# How to call an Android function with Unity code without receiving API errors

Tags: java, c#, android, kotlin, unity-game-engine

**My Goal：**
Hi,I'm developing a mobile game that require Unity to call a function in Android.

**I expect：**
The result I'm expecting is when Unity call a funtion in Android fragment, Android will return a data back to Unity, and it works.but...

**Problems I got：**
But the api inside the function doesn't work.

**The Code and process：**
(The code in Unity is called script 1, and script 2 represent Android function I tried to call)

I try to call the android function with Unity, so I used script 1(CallAndoirdFunctionFromUnity)

```
 jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.Myproject.ui.fragment.GameFragment");
 jo.Call("createData", new object[] {1});
```

to call createData function  in script 2, and I added :

```
println("startCreatData"
```

to see if the createData  function in script 2 was successfully executed .

**The Result：**
Logcat of Andorid Studio shown that the createData function was executed,but api errors occurred,this is the error message：

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.gamepon.services.RestAPIInterface.doUserDataRequestWithNumberOfData(java.lang.Integer, com.Myproject.model.request.CreateData)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.gamepon.services.RestAPIInterface.doUserDataRequestWithNumberOfData(java.lang.Integer, com.project.model.request.CreatDataRequest)' on a null object reference
```

Any method to fix this error with API? thank you.

Comment: The error seems not valid for your case. I mean the error is not because of the code you have posted. Have you used any dependencies like `com.gamepon.services`?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply,I found out that it's something related to my api interface,I'll update my question